# Why does the html disappear?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to insert `<div><p>Test</p></div>` in another DIV at the top. So I try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('form').live('submit', function(){
    var aform      = $(this);
    $('#w').append('<div><p>Test</p></div>');
  });
});
```

HTML looks like

```
<div id="w">
  <div><p>Test</p></div>
</div>
```

When I do that, it gets inserted, but goes away right after.

Try click on the Save button in this example.

http://jsfiddle.net/Rv2w7/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) and cancel the submit:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('form').live('submit', function(){
    var aform      = $(this);
    $('#w').prepend('<div><p>Test</p></div>');
    return false; //cancel `real` submit
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The page gets reloaded on submit. That's why the dynamically inserted tag disappears.

Answer (score 2):

You need to cancel the default action to prevent the form from submitting:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').live('submit', function() {
        var aform = $(this);
        $('#w').append('<div><p>Test</p></div>');
        return false;
    });
});
```

> **Updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/Rv2w7/2/**

`return false;` or `event.preventDefault()` is required to prevent the default action with `live()`.

Comment: Or, in lieu of `return false`, use `preventDefault()`, i.e.         `$('form').live('submit', function(event){
     event.preventDefault(); //...`

Answer (score 1):

Because your form gets submitted each time, you need to prevent the default action:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('form').live('submit', function(event){
    var aform      = $(this);
    $('#w').append('<div><p>Test</p></div>');
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After you click the save button the page submits, that's why its 'going away'. That happens because modifications on the current HTML only last  until the page changes or refreshes, because a new GET will be issued to the server and the unchanged version of the HTML will be retrieved, overwriting your changes.

To save something permanently to your HTML you will need to use a server-side programming language; make your program retrieve previously saved strings to a cookie or session; make your program load data from a database, etc.